# ASP.Net 4.0 URL Routing block javascript from running

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, webforms

I have article details page where i display article details like article image, date and article text. On the left side of the article i put a vertical blue line which is equal to the height of the article body, since i am not sure of the article height i use javascript to get the height of the article text container and assign that same height to the vertical blue bar (div id='ArticleBlueSide') which is 3 pixels in width.

It was working fine & blue line was also showing up without URL Routing, but when i add URL routing Blue line doesn't show up.

Below is the block of script and my HTML div contains.

I am working with ASP.Net 4.0 web form using c#.

I would appreciate if some can help me to fix this design issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var h = document.getElementById("ArticleTextArea").offsetHeight;
    h = h - 25;
    document.getElementById("ArticleBlueSide").style.height = h + "px";
});


<div id="ArticleContainer">
     <div id="ArticleBlueSide"></div>
     <div id="ArticleTextArea">
          <asp:Label ID="lblArticleDetails" CssClass="PageBodyText" runat="server"  meta:resourcekey="lblArticleDetailsResource1"></asp:Label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Example of page illustration
[image: Example]

After Implementing Solution suggested by riffnl (This has its own issue as blue line is longer than text and i cant fix it as paragraphs have padding around it. My first solution worked fine except it is not working after URL routing

[image: Example after solution]

Comment: I tried to reinitialize the script even that didnt work

Comment: just out of curiosity; why don't you let the blue bar be a background for the div and the text padded from the left side? that way the background will always stretch automatically.

Comment: That is a great idea. Superb.. I will try that option

Comment: @riffnl I implemented your solution but it creates another design issue as shown in the image adding to the question.

Comment: What does this have to do with routing? Are you using a relative path to a CSS file, and that relative path is now wrong?

Comment: @ Chris: I am confused about this also.. My CSS is working for everything else except for the part that gets the height of the div tag 'ArticleTextArea' and assign it to DIV tag 'ArticleBlueSide'. I am not sure why javascript doesnt fire after url routing

Comment: you can use negative margins (top/bottom) to cut out the unwanted space or negative padding for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the following script and put it after the div tag which solved my problem. I dont understand why it is not working if i keep this script before div tags.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var h = document.getElementById("ArticleTextArea").offsetHeight;
    h = h - 25;
    document.getElementById("ArticleBlueSide").style.height = h + "px";
});
```

I appreciate reply from other guys but this is the what i wanted script to behave.

Answer (score 0):

@riffnl's solution is the way to go - solve your padding issue like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wf6tA/

Notice that you can click a paragraph to mark or unmark it.

Comment: It is useful script but i want to have a vertical line without breaks as shown in first image..

Comment: That's what the example does - an unbroken marker line per paragraph as in your post. If you mean across paragraphs it's a simple change. http://jsfiddle.net/Wf6tA/1/

Comment: Solution is good but problem is that my paragraph tag has top padding of 10px which adds extra bit of blue line as show in the second image. I resolved the same issue by adding my original script after the div tags and it works i am not sure why it doesn't work if i keep the script before the div tags which holds the main body of the article